# WPF conditional resource selection

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I want to change back Color (or any other visual properties) on my control based on a **boolean statement** made from properties in the datacontext of the object .
let me explain it with an example :

```
public class Node
{
    public int Min ;
    public int Max ;
}
```

and then I have a wpf control like :

```
<DockPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext=<!-- an instance of node class --> >
```

now I want to select the backcolor brush from resources depeneds on if (min == max) or not .something like this :

```
if (min == max) 
BackColor = resources.fixedNodeBrush
else 
BackColor = resources.NodeBrush
```

I wanna know if it's possible to do this in xaml or do i need to write code for it ? and what's the solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to use a value converter.  You'll convert the value of (max == min) to one brush and (max != min) to another in a utility method.  Then you use that method in your XAML binding.

Take a look here: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/bencon/archive/2006/05/10/594886.aspx